# Unpublish blog content after a certain time in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, rules

> Hello i want to unpublish blog content after a certain time in drupal
>   8 how i can do it please help me

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy, there's a module called Scheduler https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler

Upon creation you can set any time you want when the content should be unpublished note that this works on CRON execution.

If you don't want to schedule unpublishing time every time you create a blog and you just want to unpublish blog lets say 1 year after publication you can do a form alter and set the default date for a scheduler today's date + 1 year.

Another option is to create a function get_blog_posts where you put a condition to exclude blog posts older than 1 year - if your page is created programmatically.

If you are using views to display you blog post it's even easier - just add filter by authoring date - authored date is less than 1 year.

Let me know which option suits you more and I can give you more details if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, (scheduler ) i don't want to schedule unpublishing time every time i create a blog and i just want to unpublish blog lets 60 days after publication .please can you help me how can i do this using rules for example

Comment: Alright lad it seems that you really like rules module, here's an working example in first comment https://groups.drupal.org/node/240678 just change the selector to authored date not a custom date field the guy is using in that example. And don't forget to turn on rules scheduler... The unpublish will happen upon CRON run.

Comment: can i use this rules in drupal 8 ?

Comment: Haven't try them but im positive that will work, if there are slight differences try them out and be a good lad and post them so that community can use it. You are on the right track but some effort is needed from your side too.